# how to create a condition where all input field is valid?

Tags: javascript, html

please help me, im doing form validation but want to create a condition in javascript where all input field is valid before according to the condition set in html code

```html
<form action="" id="calculator_form">
  <input type="number"  id="val_1" placeholder="" min="0" max="300" value=0></td>
  <input type="number"  id="val_2" placeholder="" min="0" max="200" value=0></td>
  <button class="calculate-btn" type="submit" form="calculator_form">calculate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is that only for number type inputs or do you need to check other input types as well? Also are going to submit the forum at the end of call an API worth Ajax?

Comment: What does "valid" mean here? Maybe start by writing some JS and adding an event listener, getting those values into variables and so forth. Then use, say, `if` statements and conditions/boolean logic to figure out if the values are what you want them to be.

Comment: valid here means the inserted value is in between the min and max. whenever i insert value which exceed the limit it shows popup error but the form still accept the value.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this validation function can help.
you need to append this function to submit event and it expects to return true or false based on the validation of all fields.

```
function validate() {
  let errors = {};
  let inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  let isValid = false;
  
  inputFields.forEach((input, index) => {
    let min = input.getAttribute('min'),
        max = input.getAttribute('max'),
        val = input.value;
    
    console.log(min, max, val)
    if(val >= min && val <= max) {
      isValid = true;
    }else {
      isValid = false;
    }
  })
  
  return isValid;
}
```